# Using monads: folding over part of its contents

Tags: haskell

I'm just finishing up learn you a Haskell for great good and am still struggling with how to work with Monads.

At the very end of the chapter [for a few monads more](http://learnyouahaskell.com/for-a-few-monads-more#making-monads) the author gives an exercise (second to last paragraph). Specifically, he encourages us to write a function that will collapse all the `(False, Rational)` values into a single value `(False, sum Rationals)`.

I have written out all the code that was presented in the chapter and included the relevant portion here

```
import Data.Ratio
import Control.Monad
import Control.Applicative
import Data.List (all)

newtype Prob a = Prob { getProb :: [(a, Rational)]} deriving (Show)

instance Functor Prob where
    fmap f (Prob xs) = Prob $ map (\(x, p) -> (f x, p)) xs

flatten :: Prob (Prob a) -> Prob a
flatten (Prob xs) = Prob $ concat $ map multAll xs
    where multAll (Prob innerxs, p) = map (\(x, r) -> (x, p*r)) innerxs

instance Applicative Prob where
    pure  = return
    (<*>) = ap

instance Monad Prob where
    return x = Prob [(x, 1%1)]
    m >>= f = flatten (fmap f m)
    fail _ = Prob []

data Coin = Heads | Tails deriving (Show, Eq)

coin :: Prob Coin
coin = Prob [(Heads, 1%2), (Tails, 1%2)]

loadedCoin :: Prob Coin
loadedCoin = Prob [(Heads, 1%10), (Tails, 9%10)]

flipThree :: Prob Bool
flipThree = do
    a <- coin
    b <- coin
    c <- loadedCoin
    return (all (== Tails) [a, b, c])
```

When I run this code I get

```
ghci> getProb  flipThree
[(False,1 % 40),(False,9 % 40),(False,1 % 40),(False,9 % 40),(False,1 % 40),(False,9 % 40),(False,1 % 40),(True,9 % 40)]
```

I would like to somehow filter the elements of `flipThree` that have a `False` in their first position and then sum the associated probabilities. I have written some ugly non-monadic code to do this, but am confident there is a better way.

The desired output would be

```
ghci> getProb  flipThree
[(False,31 % 40),(True,9 % 40)]
```

Comment: Note that `flipThree` itself can be implemented with applicative stuff alone; no need for the full power of monads here, since the result of one coin toss doesn't affect the subsequent coin tosses to be carried out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function that you want is

```
import Data.Function
import Data.List 

runProb :: Eq a => Prob a -> [(a, Rational)]
runProb =  map (\x -> (fst (head x), sum (map snd x))) 
         . groupBy ((==) `on` fst) 
         . getProb
```

so that

```
>runProb flipThree
[(False,31 % 40),(True,9 % 40)]
```

You could also make your type an instance of `MonadPlus` to sort-of get this result "directly":

```
instance MonadPlus Prob where 
  mzero = Prob [] 
  mplus (Prob x) (Prob y) = Prob (x++y) 

flipThree' = do
    a <- coin
    b <- coin
    c <- loadedCoin
    guard (all (== Tails) [a, b, c])

> runProb flipThree'
[((),9 % 40)]
```

Comment: Also, is there a way to do this with a monadic style, perhaps in a do expression? I would like to use this exercise to gain understanding of how to work with Monads. I see that you did something like this with the `MonadPlus` idea, but we lost the information about False (in this case it it trivial to deduce that the probability of not getting all three tails is `1%1 - 9%40`, but in more general applications there might be more than 2 choices so that reasoning won't quite work.

Comment: Firstly, I have to caution against trying to use monads everywhere. This is a fairly straightforward function - there is no reason to try to write it in a "monadic" style. do notation would not improve clarity or performance here. I imagine that you want `Prob` to group things like this "automatically" (as a part of the bind function). In this *specific* case, it is impossible, because the `runProb` function introduced an `Eq a` constraint, which wouldn't work with Monad, Functor, or Applicative.